# Google-like jQuery UI autocomplete

Tags: html, jquery-ui, autocomplete

Is it possible to send the server only the last 3 words in the textarea and to autofill the best result, letting the user keep typing in (similar to Google auto complete)?

I want the behavior to be:

1. **N**[ew]
2. **New**[er]
3. New(*SPACE*)[er]
4. **New** [York]
5. **New c**[ar]
6. **New cat** [food]
7. New cat (*TAB*) [food]
8. **New cat food** [makes]
9. ...
10. New cat food is good **for your cat's** [health]

(clarification: the [square brackets] indicates the suggestion that is automatically being typed in, the **bold text** indicates the part being sent to the server, (*TAB*) and (*SPACE*) indicates tab and space key presses)

I already a have function on the server for predicting the next word (using Markov chains) and I have integrated jQuery UI autocomplete, but currently it just sends all the text to the server and creates a list with all the suggestions to choose from, once you choose it changes the whole text.

So it eventually comes to these issues:

1. How to send only the last part?
2. How to append + select the suggested word?
3. How to select on Tab key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay - here is the solution (and here is the [result](http://text-gen.herokuapp.com/)):

1 + 2: Instead of managing a single input box, I use two identical size textarea's, the first (`#text-area`) is enables and with transparent background and the other (`#suggestions`) is disabled and with gray text color. I use the `source` callback to do all the work:

```
$('#text-area').autocomplete({ ...

source: function( request, response ) {
        if (request.term.length < 3) {
          return false;
        }
        $.getJSON( $SCRIPT_ROOT + '/_get_word', {
          term: request.term
        }, function(data) {
            $('#suggestions').val(data.result) //suggestion is the disabled textarea
          }
          );
        return false;
      }, 
 ...
    });
});
```

3: the tab key selection is done with triggering the autocomplete search event:

```
$('#text-area').live( "keydown",'textarea', function( event ) {
        if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB) {
          event.preventDefault();
          $('#text-area').val($('#suggestions').val());
          $("#text-area").autocomplete('search', $('#text-area').val());
      }
});
```